# Traefik delivering two different ports on same docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, traefik

I have a problem with traefik. The situation:
I have a docker gitlab with gitlab-registry activated, no problem with that.
My gitlab answer on port 80 and registry on port 80 as well, and this is not a problem nether (tried with port mapping and worked well.

Now I try to configure these guys in traefik and that's when problems occur. When ther is just one router and one service, all good but when I try to add the registry I have an error:

The involved part in the docker-compose file:

```yaml
labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlab.rule=Host(`git.example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlab.service=gitlabservice
      - traefik.http.services.giltabservice.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlab.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlabregistry.rule=Host(`registry.example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlabregistry.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlabregistry.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlabregistry.service=gitlabregistryservice
      - traefik.http.services.giltabregistryservice.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      - traefik.http.routers.gitlabregistry.entrypoints=websecure
```

And the errors I have in traefik:

> time="2021-03-27T08:48:20Z" level=error msg="the service "gitlabservice@docker" does not exist" entryPointName=websecure routerName=gitlab@docker

> time="2021-03-27T08:48:20Z" level=error msg="the service "gitlabregistryservice@docker" does not exist" entryPointName=websecure routerName=gitlabregistry@docker

Thanks in advance if you have any idea.

Comment: You are specifying the servce for the gitlabregistry router as 'gitlabregistryservice' but that service isn't listed as 'traefik.http.services.gitlabregistryservice...' anywhere.  Specify a load balancer for 'traefik.http.services.gitlabregistryservice.loadbalancer.server.port=5000' or whatever it should be.